# Building a C++ Program in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

To my knowledge, I have followed all of the steps to build a C++ program in Visual Studio Code on Windows 10. I have `gcc-7.1.0-64` installed under `C:/MinGW`, the `C/C++` extension installed in VS Code, and have configured a build task for my `HelloWorld.cpp`.

***The issue:***

When I try to build the program by opening the Command Palette and then typing `Tasks: Run Build Task`, It displays the error:

> No Build Task found. Press 'Configure Build Task' to define one.

despite the fact that I have already done exactly that. I am probably missing something simple, but no tutorial or documentation I could find anywhere explains how to make this work. Any help is appreciated.

**HelloWorld.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello world\n";
}
```

**c_cpp_properties.json** (irrelevant Mac/Linux setup omitted from snippet)

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "C:/MinGW/include/c++/7.1.0/*"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "C:/MinGW/include/c++/7.1.0/*"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 2
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskName": "HelloWorld.cpp",
      "command": "c++",
      "args": ["-g", "HelloWorld.cpp"],
      "type": "shell"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @RobLourens's comment for the answer.

> The easiest way for tasks 2.0 is, run "Configure default build task", which will let you pick the build command, and set the group property for you.

I soon realized that it adds a line under the `"group"` section of the specified build task in `tasks.json`: (*may be added manually to circumvent the formal method*)

```
"isDefault": true,
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `"isBuildCommand": true` inside your task.

Comment: IntelliSense complains about that: `The property isBuildCommand is deprecated. Use the group property instead. See also the 1.14 release notes.`

Comment: That's the property from the old tasks format. The easiest way for tasks 2.0 is, run "Configure default build task", which will let you pick the build command, and set the group property for you.